# Move the chat window to the right side of Gmail with the preview pane enabled

Tags: gmail, chat, user-interface

I am using Gmail with too many labels with multiple levels. I also have the Preview Pane lab enabled.

I want to move the chat window to the right side. It was previously there. But I am not able to move it now. Please guide me to do the same.

[image: Current layout of chat window]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think it's compatible with the *Preview Pane* feature. Even if you have them both enabled, the Preview Pane has precedence and it moves the chat list to the left side.

You can disable the *Preview Pane* lab: Go to **Mail settings -> Labs ->** Search for **Preview pane** in the page **-> Set it to Disable -> Click Save Changes** at the bottom of the page.

To enable the right side chat window: go to **Mail settings -> Labs ->** Search for **Right-side chat** in the page **-> Set it to Enable -> ClickSave Changes** at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, Its Simple.
There is a lab feature developed by Emily C

1. Goto the Settings in your Mail Account.
2. Under the Labs Tab, search for Right-Side Chat
3. Click Enable.
4. Save Changes.

There you go! :D

Comment: Only that it’s incompatible with the Preview Pane view. Please read the answer and comments before posting.